# Append Symbols like ♀ to an input text field

Tags: javascript, special-characters

I'm creating a simple search utility and it needs to be able to use the characters ♀ and ♂. To make it easier, I'm creating buttons to append those characters to the field. However, I can't figure out how to get those to properly append to the field.

I'm using the following right now:

```
function addFemale()
{
    document.getElementById('searchfield').value += "♀";
}
```

However, that just adds `â™€` to the text field. How can I make this work?

Comment: Make sure you've saved your file as UTF-8 and that your server is serving it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add [meta](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">` on page in `<head>` tag. 
This meta tag specifies the character encoding for the HTML document.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the JavaScript code was in an external .js file

Comment: Why do you believe this is the problem?

Comment: I've just tried to create `index.html` without `<meta charset="UTF-8">` and separated file `script.js` with `document.getElementById('searchfield').value += "♀";` Before adding meta i have `â™€` and after adding meta I have ♀ in input.

Comment: This ended up fixing it for me.